# ¿Por qué mi función super no funciona?

Tags: python

hola soy super nuevo jeje pero la neta y quisiera saber porque usar la función `super()` no me funciona. Este es mi código:

```py
class App_Origen:
     def __init__(self, _name, _parts):
          self._name = _name
          self._parts = _parts
       
     def show(self):
         print(self.name, self.parts)

class Secound_App(App_Origen):
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__(_name, _parts)
       
       
     def print(self):
         print(self.name, self.parts)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Secound_App("walter", "yourparts")
    obj.print()
```

Sin embargo, me sale este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/home/laboratory-01/Desktop/examen/MasterApp.py", line 20, in <module>
 obj = Secound_App("walter", "Higgings")   
 TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Comment: La funcion __init__ de tu clase Secound_App solo recibe un argumento (la instancia en si). No recibe los otros dos argumentos que le estas pasando cuando la instancias.

Comment: El problema no es super. Super esta funcionando bien. Me explico?

Comment: el problema es el inicializador de la clase `Secound_App` pues tal como lo tienes solo recibe 1 parámetro, solo debes indicarlos y se soluciona el problema

Comment: entonces tengo que añadir los parametros del __init__ de la primera clase a la otra funicion __init__ de la segunda clase?

Comment: Asi es. Sin embargo, si quieres que el __init__ de la segunda clase sea exactamente igual al de la primera hay un camino menos repetitivo...

Comment: Todo depende de cual sea tu objetivo.

Comment: solo quisiera pasar los atributos de la primera clase a la segunda y oi que super toma el metodo de una clase

Comment: como se heredaria entonces correctamente perdon ?

Comment: A que te refieres? Que atributos? App_Origen no tiene ningun atributo (ademas de los proporcionados por Python). En cambio, una instancia de App_Origen SI los tiene.

Comment: como puedo heredar correctamente porfavor

Comment: No se que decirte, solo que vas en buen camino. Perdon, solo queria ayudar, no confundir. Solo has que el __init__ de la segunda clase tenga los argumentos del de la primera.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, en la llamada a la super clase tienes que pasarle los parámetros que espera:

```
class Secound_App(App_Origen):
    def __init__(self, _name, _parts):
        super().__init__(_name, _parts)
```

Segundo, los nombre de los campos son `_name` y `_parts`

```
def print(self):
    print(self._name, self._parts)
```

Esos nombres quedaron definidos en el `__init__` de la clase base:
self._name = _name
self._parts = _parts

[Nota: El prefijo `_` se usa convencionalmente sólo variables privadas; el nombre de los parámetros se especifica convencionalmente sin `_`. Lo deje igual]

#### Demo

```
class App_Origen:
    def __init__(self, _name, _parts):
        self._name = _name
        self._parts = _parts

    def show(self):
        print(self.name, self.parts)

class Secound_App(App_Origen):
    def __init__(self, _name, _parts):
        super().__init__(_name, _parts)


    def print(self):
        print(self._name, self._parts)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = Secound_App("walter", "yourparts")
    obj.print()
```

produce:

```
walter yourparts

Process finished with exit code 0
```